# FID as a metric to evaluate the quality of synthetic datasets (Non GAN generated) for training models for a given classification task

Tags: conv-neural-network, kullback-leibler, gan, synthetic-data

I am working on a problem of generating synthetic data (algorithmically by blender, not using GANs) to aid the training of some CNN for a classification ask. Ideally, I want to generate an algorithm that generates synthetic samples as close to real samples as possible. But it happens that it is very hard to design this algoritm and define hyperparamters just looking at the results and guessing if they are similar enough to the real dataset. It is also not doable to generate many datasets and decide the hyperparameters according to the final classification metric, since the training the CNN takes too long.

So I want to get some good methodology to tune my synthetic generator without having to look at them and without having to go through the costly process of training the downstream model. My idea was trying to calculate the Frechet Distance (FID) between my synthetic dataset and a real data and test the effects of different changes on the algorithmic according to the change on the FID metric.

My question is, is it a reasonable idea? I am using this for my master thesis so I feel that I need a reasonable methodology.
Another question is, I know about KL divergence. Would that be a better idea?

Comment: 1. What is "blender"? 2. Yes, you can use any metric you want. That said, please do your research and find a paper doing what you describe or what you want to extend. Even the Wikipedia article on [Fréchet inception distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_inception_distance) discusses some of its short-comings and it is unclear how you plan to overcome them. 3. I would stick with KL at this point as it is most widely used. You already have "one innovation" using "blender", try to see if that works as expected and then extend the methodology further.

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks for the comment. Blender is a commonly used 3D modelling tool. It is not that much an innovation as I have already seen some papers on synthetic data using Blender. But this is not important, the key idea here is generating synthetic data not with GANs but algorithmicaly