# Where to start creating a -synthetic 3D object- based neural network in combination with sensor data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, synthetic-data, sensor-data

I have a question on where to start with a project of mine. It includes a wide variety of expertise, so I am not sure if am at the right part of stack exchange. My project is as such:
I have a cube that has a known defect on the inside and I have an ultrasonic sensor.

I would like to create synthetic data of cubes with varying shapes and internal damages and simulate the sensor response.

I know how to draw a 3D model in Catia or Inventor, how to acquire sensordata in Matlab and how to program a neural network in Python. I want to randomize 3D objects and use these models to create a virtual sensor response. Can I use the software described above, or should I maybe use something like a game engine for this?

I have found that blender could be used to create the 3D models and that I can use pytorch 3D to run a machine learning algorithm on meshes. My initial thought is that Simulink would be best used to do the sensor simulations, but I am hesitant because I expect that it also requires the Simulink 3D animation, the model-based Calibration Toolbox and a lot of other costly add-ons.

Can anybody share his or her experience with combining 3D models, sensor data and machine learning?

Comment: Here is a similar question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569990/fid-as-a-metric-to-evaluate-the-quality-of-synthetic-datasets-non-gan-generated  so far without answers --- I think you need to give people more information, more to work with, for this question to have much chance for an answer!

Comment: Thank you for your advice! when I have more information, I will post it here